# Spoil link-spoofing attempts?

Tags: feature-request

I just noticed that it is quite easy to spoof links on SE. Maybe this hasn't happened, yet, but I imagine at some point, one of the non-technical oriented sites will have an issue with this.

I don't know the best solution, or maybe there is something at work server-side that I can't see, but I have always been fond of how Slashdot shows the linked domain in brackets after the text.

Here is a spoof:

[meta.serverfault.com/questions/419407/…](http://google.com)

Here is a suggestion:

[meta.serverfault.com/questions/419407/…](http://google.com) [google.com]

Or some other sort of warning, though I'm not fond of the "you are leaving our site..." pages.

Comment: Yay for Slashdot style, Nay for warning page/box. IIRC Slashdot also has that feature as a user-configurable option.

Comment: @muru In fact, they have 3 options, the middle option being "Show the links domain only in recommended situations."

Comment: This could be [very](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emphasis) [wikipedia.org] [annoying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crazy_Frog) [wikipedia.org] in [text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_(literary_theory)) [wikipedia.org] that [contains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Container_Revolution) [wikipedia.org] many [links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperlink) [wikipedia.org] in close [succession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecological_succession) [wikipedia.org]. In any case, any actual link markup abuse like in your example would be pretty blatant, and easy to edit / flag.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I agree that it is annoying for some users, so I'm not saying it's a great solution. But your argument that the spoof is easily caught assumes this happens before unaware users click the link, not to mention the spoofers are likely more clever than me at this.

Comment: Perhaps a middle option for SE would be to only show it for new users, whom I assume are the ones most likely to perform such shenanigans.